# get data behind " , " to take phrase by python

Tags: database, python-3.x, xlrd, xlwt, phrases

I want to get data in Column D behind " , " in the end of the sentence from left to right to get phrase in link bio:

[1]:( http://prntscr.com/fye9hi) "here"

Someone cant help me please ....

This is my code but it cant go like i want.

```
import xlrd 

file_location = "C:/Users/admin/DataKH.xlsx"
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
print(sheet.nrows)
print(sheet.ncols)


for rows in range(sheet.nrows):
    row_0 = sheet.cell_value(rows,0)

from xlwt import Workbook 
import xlwt
from xlwt import Formula


workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)



data = [sheet.cell_value(row,3) for row in range(sheet.nrows)]
data1 = [sheet.cell_value(row, 4) for row in range(sheet.nrows)]


workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')

for index, value in enumerate(data):
    sheet.write(index, 0, value)

for index, value in enumerate(data1): 
    sheet.write(index, 1 , value) 

workbook.save('output.xls')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `split(",")` method? It returns a list of phrases so you can easily iterate through it though.

---

@MinhTuấnNgô: I'm confused with `xlrd`'s syntax so I switched to `pandas` instead.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('SampleData.xlsx')

df['Extracted Address'] = pd.Series((cell.split(',')[-1] for cell in df['Address']), index = df.index)
```

Not sure what you mean by 'getting the data after the comma' but this shows a way to manipulate the cell data.

After you've finished formatting the data, you can export it back to excel using `df.to_excel(<filepath>)`

---

For `xlrd`, you can iterate through a specific column using this syntax:
`for row in ws.col(2)[1:]:`
This should skip the first row (as taken care of in the case of `pandas` anyway) and iterate all remaining rows.

Comment: Omg, it so useful. But, how can I do that in column because i want it run row by row. Sorry im newbie! @Khanh Nguyen

Comment: @MinhTuấnNgô: I have included an edit in the answer, please check it out. The code should omit the first phrase that comes BEFORE the 1st comma and leave the rest intact.

Comment: thôi topic này em viết bằng tiếng việt luôn cho dê hiểu anh nhé. Em đang có file excel trên muốn lấy dư liệu ở sau dấu phẩy cuối cùng trong cột D. Em có thử như anh chỉ nhưng báo lôi từ "File" như đây ạ:  http://prntscr.com/fykj4p . Anh check giúp em với ạ!  @KhanhNguyen

Comment: @Minh: sorry, forgot to change the variable name :D `file` should be `df` instead :D
P.s: online 4rum so...

Comment: but wait, what about "ws.col" in   " for row in ws.col(2)[1:]: " ? I dont know ws.col mean ? @KhanhNguyen

Comment: `ws.col(<column number>)` should return the column with the index of <column number>  in the worksheet (noted as `ws = workbook.active` or `workboot.get_sheet_by_index()`)(0 for A, 1 for B, 2 for C etc.)

The `[1:]` should have you skip the first row in the column as it usually contains the headers.

Comment: If you want to get the phrase after the last comma, just substitute `''.join(cell.split(',')[1:])`with `cell.split(',')[-1]`

Comment: I can't imagine what i could be if not your help. Thank you so much!   I self-learn so it's so diffucult  for me. So so thank you! Best regardness

Comment: wait, i got a problem. when i run code, it run but if i assign in column it pulled data the last row for all column. http://prntscr.com/fzi6bf . In case, what should i do?

Comment: if I Print(ed) under For it give all data of column split, but if i take out of For, it's only give the last row and pulled data all column. Do you know why?

Comment: really :))) So what should i do now?? :(((

Comment: hmm...  we  can be friend on FB or are you in Ha noi we can face to face. I think face to face is the best!!! @Khanh Nguyen